# How to Hide UITabbarController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have implemented UITabBarController in my applicationm. The code of it is as follows:

```
MainCollection *mainView = [[MainCollection alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainCollection" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mainNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainView];

    mainView = (MainCollection *)mainNav.topViewController;
    mainView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    ShowFavourites *showVC = [[ShowFavourites alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowFavourites" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *showNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:showVC];
    showNav.title=@"Favourites";
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    [tabBar setViewControllers:@[mainNav,showNav]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBar];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
```

My first Screen is **MainCollection** I should show tabBar in this view. suppose the next view is **SubCategory** but when I navigate to SubCategory, on this view I want to hide Tabbar then How can I hide it or remove it from only **SubCategory** view?

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is confusing question please describe in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has a very simple solution. You should have tried harder. 
In the View in which you want to hide the `UITabBar` simply add

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Here access these links for SO itself. You will easily find the answer :-

[Show/Hide TabBarController in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356828/show-hide-tabbarcontroller-in-iphone)

[How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller)

[How to Hide Tab Bar Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466829/how-to-hide-tab-bar-controller)

[Is it possible to hide the tabbar when a button is pressed to allow a full screen view of the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209582/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-tabbar-when-a-button-is-pressed-to-allow-a-full-scree)

[How to hide UITabBarController programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257178/how-to-hide-tab-bar-controller-programmatically)

[How to hide an iPhone Tab Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499892/how-to-hide-an-iphone-tab-bar)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to hide the tabbar just use parent navigation controller for push to subcategory screen

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:subCategoryObj animated:YES];
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is not advisable because when setting `self.title` in the pushed view controller it will not update the navigation controller. The other answer is far better.